# Adding GIF or Image to tkinter's ScrolledText widget. (Or another implementation of chat with animated emotes like BTTV)

Tags: python, tkinter, chat, twitch

i'm working on creating a chat, like on a twitch, in my project using Tkinter. Is it possible to make a chat widget with animated (and not only) emojis in messages?

[This is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNN7q.jpg)

code:

```
def print_mess(self, mess):

    self.console.configure(state='normal')
    self.console.insert(END, mess.formated_time() + " ", 'timesign')
    self.console.tag_config('timesign', foreground='#C0C0C0')
    self.console.insert(END, mess.username, mess.username)
    self.console.tag_config(mess.username, foreground=mess.usercolor)
    self.console.insert(END, ": ", 'mess')
    self.console.insert(END, mess.message + "\n", 'mess')
    self.console.tag_config('mess', foreground='#FFFFFF')
    self.console.yview(END)  # autoscroll
    self.console.configure(state='disabled')
```

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. It might require a lot of work, however, since tkinter doesn't provide out-of-the-box support for animated gifs.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways one way is to use a label and add it to the Text widget using `window_create()`

Example: (drag and drop a gif. click on the gif to play, Modify this to suit your need).

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import windnd

class Text(tk.Text):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.gif = {}
        self.index = 0
        self.delay = 20

        self.currentlyPlaying = None
        self.currentId = None
        
    def insert_gif(self, path):
        gif = GifMaker(path)

        label = tk.Label(image=gif.frames[0], bd=3)
        label.bind('<1>', lambda event: self.playGif(label))
        self.window_create("end", window=label)

        self.gif[label] = gif
        self.playGif(label)
  
    
    def playGif(self, label):
        
        if self.currentlyPlaying is None:
            self.currentlyPlaying = label

        if self.currentlyPlaying != label:  # makes sure only one gif is played at any time
            self.index = 0
            self.currentlyPlaying.configure(image=self.gif[self.currentlyPlaying].frames[0])
            self.currentlyPlaying = label

            self.after_cancel(self.currentId)      
        
        self.index += 1
   
        if self.index == self.gif[self.currentlyPlaying].n_frames-1:
            self.index = 0
        
        self.currentlyPlaying.configure(image=self.gif[self.currentlyPlaying].frames[self.index])
        
        if self.index != 0:
            self.currentId = self.after(self.delay, self.playGif, self.currentlyPlaying)
                 
    
class GifMaker:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

        self.image = Image.open(path)
        self.n_frames = self.image.n_frames #  number of frames
 
        self.frames = []
        self.duration = 0  # total duration of the gif
        
        for x in range(self.n_frames):
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.copy())

            self.duration += self.image.info['duration']

            self.frames.append(img)
            self.image.seek(x)
     
        self.delay = self.duration//self.n_frames  

def dropped(file):
    text.insert_gif(file[0])


root = tk.Tk()

text = Text()
text.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

windnd.hook_dropfiles(root, func=dropped)
root.mainloop()
```

other way is to use `.image_create()` to create the image and use `.image_configure()` to update the image. (Recommended)

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import windnd

class Text(tk.Text):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.gif = {}
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.delay = 10


    def changeCursor(self, event):
        if event.type == '7':
            self.configure(cursor="hand2")

        else:
            self.configure(cursor="xterm")
    
    def insert_gif(self, path):
        gif = GifMaker(path)

        index = self.image_create("end", image=gif.frames[0])
        self.tag_add(f"{index}", 'end-2c')

        self.gif[index] = gif

        self.tag_bind(f"{index}", "<1>", lambda event: self.playGif(index))
        self.tag_bind(f"{index}", "<Enter>", self.changeCursor)
        self.tag_bind(f"{index}", "<Leave>", self.changeCursor)
        
        self.playGif(index)
    
    def playGif(self, label):
        
        self.frame_index += 1
        self.image_configure(label, image=self.gif[label].frames[self.frame_index])
        
        
        if self.frame_index == self.gif[label].n_frames-1:
            self.frame_index = 0
            self.image_configure(label, image=self.gif[label].frames[0])
        
        if self.frame_index != 0:
            #self.after(self.gif[label].delay, self.playGif, label)
            self.after(self.delay, self.playGif, label)
            
        
class GifMaker:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

        self.image = Image.open(path)
        self.n_frames = self.image.n_frames #  number of frames
 
        self.frames = []
        self.duration = 0  # total duration of the gif
        
        for x in range(self.n_frames):
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image.copy())

            self.duration += self.image.info['duration']

            self.frames.append(img)
            self.image.seek(x)
     
        self.delay = self.duration//self.n_frames  


def dropped(file):
    text.insert_gif(file[0])

root = tk.Tk()

text = Text()
text.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

windnd.hook_dropfiles(root, func=dropped)
root.mainloop()
```

<sub>(make sure only one gif is played at any instance by adding conditions like the above method)</sub>

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for informative answer. I wanted to clarify if this will work with many (20 - 30) gifs in one window, and will they be synchronized?

Comment: @kaizer as you may place as many gifs as you want in one window. _" will they be synchronized?"_ By this if you mean will you be able to play many gifs simultaneously. The answer is No. But you can play multiple gifs at a time if you modify the code but it won't look good. `.after` method will be scheduling the playGif method to execute in this case every 10 seconds. So when a function is executing Tkinter will not process any other events until the method has completed executing.

Comment: @kaizer So it would be better if you add conditions like the first case to allow only one gif to be played at a time. Also, If you found this helpful pls considering marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick mark beside the answer.